# SSMS System Functions not right color

Tags: ssms, ssms-2016

I recently installed SSMS 2016 and when I opened some code I have saved it looked a little strange. Then I noticed that a lot of keywords were not the right color. I figured out that all System Functions were not being colored correctly in the text editor. I did some digging but nothing I tried worked. I eventually went to try and manually set the color of the system functions by going Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Fonts and Colors. I could not find "SQL- System Functions" anywhere. Actually all of the list options that start with "SQL" were not available. I took a screenshot of the menu for reference.

Does anyone know how to fix this? the functions still work but its driving me nuts.[Missing Font and Color option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eoe9I.jpg)

Comment: Did you try to [reset](http://imgur.com/a/sNfmz) it back to defaults?

Comment: yep, I even tried to import a new template, which worked, but it didn't resolve the issue. I've reinstalled but after work today im going to completely wipe it clean of ssms and try to reinstall.